# blender not responding when i click on UV editor

Tags: uv-image-editor

so I've been using blender 2.80 lately and for some reason when I choose the UV editor option, blender stops responding, I then check my task manager and it says that it is not responding, yet its not using my GPU, CPU, or a lot of ram, (1.8gb ram usage only) and I can't figure out why its not responding, I also had a problem where my graphic card just decided to not show/post anything while using blender, I tried changing the ports but it still said that its not responding. I had to restart my pc for it to work but I don't know why that happened and I'm assuming its blender because I was using it all day and I didn't run into any issues until I opened up the UV editor in blender, I'm using a Radeon graphics card if that's relevant to the question. I can't find any solutions online and any answer that can help with this issue will be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Blender version?

Comment: im using blender 2.80